# Dynamically adding a textview to a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I wanted to dynamically add textview to a linear layout.

I have used the following code:

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewlayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView tv = new TextView(viewrecords.this);
    tv.setId(1);
    tv.setTextSize(15);
    tv.setText("test adding");
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    ll.addView(tv);
```

Iam not getting the textview added.Can any one help me out to solve the issue.

Comment: Hey do u have anything else in that linear layout

Comment: I test your code it display test adding textview in my case.

Comment: It doesn't seems any problem in your code.May be your textview is hiding behind some view.You just try this i am not sure about this.try to place your textview in .xml and get the parameter of that textview and use the same parameter in java file.So that you can get your textview at respective position.

Comment: Actually my linear layout is having some more content and when i removed all those extra content the textview seems to be adding.

Comment: Rakshi ::Thank you for your question. Your question ,cleared my issue..thank you...

Answer (score 4):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// setContentView(R.layout.rainbow);
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("FIRST");
tv1.setTextSize(10);
tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
tv2.setTextSize(10);
tv2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tv2.setText("MIDDLE");

TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
tv3.setTextSize(10);
tv3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tv3.setText("LAST");

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
ll.addView(tv1);
ll.addView(tv2);
ll.addView(tv3);    
setContentView(ll);
}
```

see this Example we have clear idea http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_linear-layouts_2/

Comment: Suppose I have 'List<String>' and I want to show each 'String' in 'TextView'. How can I achieve that? Each 'TextView' should have distinct id.